# JAX-RS @EJB injection gives NullPointerException

Tags: jax-rs, ejb, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy a war file to run on WildFly Swarm. While doing a GET request, a NullPointerException occurs because an injection fails and the reference is, obviously, null.

**SomeDao.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface SomeDao {
    public List<MyEntity> listAll();
    public void store(MyEntity entity);
}
```

**SpecializedDao.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class SpecializedDao implements SomeDao {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public SpecializedDao() {}

    @Override
    public List<MyEntity> listAll() {
        return this.entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT entity FROM MyEntity entity", MyEntity.class)
                .getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void store(MyEntity entity) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Then, there's the endpoint where I need to inject a *SpecializedDao* instance.

**MyEndpoint.java**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Stateless
@Path("/something")
public class MyEndpoint {

    @EJB
    private SomeDao dao;

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response test() {
        MyEntity testEntity = new MyEntity("something", "something");

        dao.store(testEntity);

        return Response.ok("All done!").build();
    }


}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.2" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

The NullPointerException is launched at *dao.store(testEntity)*, because dao references a null object. I'm pretty sure the persistence.xml file is correct because the EntityManager works on another test case, so I think the problem is at injection.

Where did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other things you can check.

1. Is your beans.xml located in the correct folder (ie in WEB-INF in case of a webapp/war) ?
2. Did you include the Swarm CDI fraction/dependency (org.wildfly.swarm:cdi) ?
3. I'm not a Swarm expert but it may be that the CDI fraction only works when beans are injected "à la JSR-299" that is using `java.inject.@Inject` (rather than using @EJB).

   ```
       @Inject
       private SomeDao dao;
   ```
4. Ultimately: try with bean-discovery-mode="all" in beans.xml (...even though "annotated" seems correct)

Comment: Ok, so, some steps forward have been made, thanks! I added the CDI dependency (I thought I had already added it, but turns out that I did not!), changed the bean discovery to "all". Now the SpecializedDao is injected correctly.

But still, the NullPointerException is still there. Now the problem is the entity manager injection, because the Exception is propagated from the same line of the store() method (as before).

I'll try to see if I can pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to put a "beans.xml" file (under WEB-INF/META-INF folder) ?

Comment: I already did put it... To complete the code, I added it in my first post